# Unit test doesnt let me use a namespace after I've referenced it

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, namespaces

I have two seperate libraries wich I created UnitTests for both, on the first one I need to test a function that requires me to use the second library function as well. On the First class, I've referenced the second one, but when I try to add the `using` for the namespace, the namespace doesnt appear.

> EDIT: After many attempts it came down to close and open VS several
>   times rebuild the libaries and then reference them again

Comment: right click UnitTestProject --> Add --> Reference. Choose solution under projects and mark the projects to add a reference.

Comment: @KasperDue ok after I closed and reopen VS it work somehow. Post an answer so I can mark it has correct if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click UnitTestProject --> Add --> Reference. Choose solution under projects and mark the projects to add a reference.